# SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost flutter with mysql1 package

Tags: mysql, flutter, crud

I am building flutter app with MySQL (not using phpMyAdmin) using mysql1 package (mysql1: ^0.19.2). I tried to make connection with the local host database. But got below error.

```
E/flutter ( 7011): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno 
= 111, address = localhost
```

The code I used given below

```
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

class Mysql {
  static String host = 'localhost',
      user = 'root',
      password = 'abcd@1234',
      db = 'fluttertest';
  static int port = 3306;

  Mysql();

  Future<MySqlConnection> getConnection() async {
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
        host: host, port: port, user: user, password: password, db: db);
    return await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
  }
}
```

This is the function I used to check whether the connection works or not.

```
  void _dbCheck() {
    db.getConnection().then((value) async {
      await value.query('insert into user (email, password, ) values (?, ?)',
          ['Bob', 'bob@bob.com']);
    });
  }
```

Can anyone please help me to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try instead 127.0.0.1

Comment: @nbk Still same error

Comment: are you sure that the server is running? check the mysql error log

Comment: @nbk Yes. The server is running. Error thrown in flutter console which stated that connection refused

Comment: the error message tell me that there isn't a server at the port, so try first to connct with the mysql client and still please llook´in the error log

Comment: @nbk It worked for ```host = 10.0.2.2```. Thank you.